# move files with specific extension to folder in higher hierarchy

Tags: powershell, move, get-childitem

All my files are in specific folders:

```
17\1\1\PRO
17\1\2\PRO
17\2\1\PRO
xx\xx\xx\PRO
```

- 17 is the year (so 18 for next year etc)
- the first 1 is the folder specifying the case number (can be up to 100).
- The second 1 is the sub parts on the case number.

That last 1 has a folder `PRO` in it where all data resides.

We need to move these files, but the files need to stay inside their respective "PRO" folders.

For example:

- a file in `17\1\1\pro\xxx\www\` needs to go to `17\1\1\pro\movies`
- a file in `17\2\2\pro\xxdfsdf\eeee\` needs to go to `17\2\2\pro\movies`.

The movies folder should get created if there are files to move.

I need to get a part of the full name of a file and move the file there to the "movie" folder. The problem is I do not know how to split the full name, add \movies to it and move the files there.

This is my code so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $mypath -Recurse -File -Filter $extension | select $_Fullname |
Move-Item -Force -Destination ($_Fullname.Split("pro"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many directories there are, I would do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $mypath -Recurse -File -Filter $extension | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.FullName.IndexOf('\PRO\') -gt 0) {
        $Destination = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName.Substring(0,$_.FullName.IndexOf('\PRO\') + 5) -ChildPath 'movies';
        New-Item $Destination -ItemType Directory -ea Ignore;
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Destination;
    } else {
        throw ("\PRO\ path not found in '$($_.FullName)'");
    }
}
```

This will work fine as long as your paths only have `\pro\` once.  If they have it more than once like `customer\pro\17\pro\17\1\1\pro\xx\yy\zz\www` and you need the last index, then use `$_.FullName.LastIndexOf('\pro\')`.

If you've got `\pro\` directories both before and after the directory that `.\pro\movies\` is in, well, you're in trouble.  You'll probably have to find a different point of reference.

Comment: only 1 pro in the entire path structure, so this will work.

Comment: That will create a **file** `movies` in the proper loation with the content of the moved file. You should do test-path for folder $Destination first and then move the file with it's own name probaply checking if it already exists to not overwrite same name from other subfolder.

Comment: Insert `If (!(Test-Path $Destination)){md $Destination|out-Null}` in front of the move-item line.

Comment: @LotPings Fair enough, I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

If the destination is always "movies subdirectory of the grandparent directory of the file's directory" you can build the destination path relative to the file's location:

```
Get-ChildItem ... | ForEach-Object {
    $dst = Join-Path $_.Directory '..\..\movies'
    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Type Directory -Path $dst | Out-Null
    }
    Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $dst
}
```

If the `PRO` directory is your anchor you could use a regular expression replacement like this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem ... | ForEach-Object {
    $dst = $_.Directory -replace '^(.*\\\d+\\\d+\\\d+\\PRO)\\.*', '$1\movies'
    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Type Directory -Path $dst | Out-Null
    }
    Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $dst
}
```

Comment: well the grandparent directory is not allways certain. There can be thousands of directories inside a pro folder with each multiple sub directories splitting in more directories. It's never certain how many subfolders there are

Comment: If that's the case just make the destination subdirectory a parameter to be fed into the cmdlet/function.

Comment: You need to insert an `If (!(Test-Path $dst)){md $Dst|out-Null}` in front of the move for the 2nd version. +1.

Comment: @LotPings Indeed. I had missed the "movies folder should get created if there are files to move" part. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

With a set of folders

```
17\1\1\PRO
17\1\2\PRO
17\2\1\PRO
```

You could try the following

```
$RootPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder\*\*\*\pro
```

`$RootPaths` will then contain all 3 paths mentioned above and the code below will move all files to the appropriate directory.

```
ForEach( $Path in $RootPaths)
{
    $Movies = Join-Path $Path -Child "Movies"
    If( -not (Test-Path $Movies ) ) { New-Item -Path $Movies -ItemType Directory }

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File -Filter $Extension | 
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$( $Path )\Movies"
}
```

This way it doesn't matter how many levels down your files are. They always get moved to the same directory.

Comment: IMO you should remove the `-Path` from `Move-Item` as it is already receiving the file object from the pipe.

Comment: you can't use $rootpaths, since you don't know upfront what the root path will be. that changes depending on down which subdirectory you are:
17\1\1\pro gathers everything below 
17\2\1\pro gathers everything below

Comment: Michael, in Powershell the asterisk character can be used to refer to all folders. That means `$RootPaths` will contains all folders that have a pro folder 2 levels down from the root.

Comment: The mentioned flaw is still present and your script suffers from the same problem - if the movies folder isn't created first the file is moved to the name movies.

Comment: OK, added creation of directory. Well spotted.