# I want to move files with selected extensions in another folder by checking nested folder.can anyone help me

Tags: powershell

Looking to move files with selected extensions in another folder by checking nested folder.
Can anyone help me.

Comment: hey user, looks like you are new here, I recommend having a look at this to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move files with specific extension to folder in higher hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591348/move-files-with-specific-extension-to-folder-in-higher-hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

To get you started something like the below will help:

```
#Set Path
$sourcePath = "c:\Windows\Logs"
$extension = ".txt"
$destinationPath = "c:\logs"

#Use Get Child Item to find all files with extension
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$sourcePath\*" -Include "*$extension"

#loop through each file and move to destination
foreach($file in $files){

Move-Item -Destination $destinationPath -Path $file.FullName -Confirm:$false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SourceFolder = "C:\test\source"
$DestinationFolder = "C:\test\dest"
$exstension = "txt"

if(!(Test-Path $DestinationFolder))
{
    [void](New-Item -ItemType Directory $DestinationFolder)  
}

foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -Filter "*.$exstension"))
{
    $DestinationPath = "$DestinationFolder\$($item.Name)"
    if(Test-Path $DestinationPath)
    {
        Write-Host "File `"$DestinationPath`" already exists. File has not been copied." -BackgroundColor Red
        continue 
    }

    Try
    {
        Copy-Item $item.FullName $DestinationPath -ErrorAction Stop 
        Write-Host "Copied `"$($item.FullName)`" to `"$DestinationPath`"" -BackgroundColor Green
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Error while copying `"$($item.FullName)`" : $($_.ExeptionMessage)"
    }    
}
```